# Cannot scroll Vaadin Dialog with touchscreen

Tags: css, scroll, dialog, vaadin, touchscreen

I am unable to vertically scroll a Vaadin Dialog containing a VerticalLayout taller than the screen when using a touchscreen device; the Dialog scrolls normally in a desktop environment using the mouse wheel.

This is the interested HTML:

```
<vaadin-dialog-overlay id="overlay" focus-trap="" with-backdrop="" opened="" role="dialog" style="z-index: 201;">
  <flow-component-renderer appid="ROOT" nodeid="94" style="">
    <div class="draggable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <vaadin-vertical-layout class="genericDialog" theme="padding spacing" style="width: 100%;">
        <vaadin-horizontal-layout class="titleDialog" theme="spacing">
          [stuff...]
        </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
        <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="padding spacing" style="width: 100%;">
          [stuff...]
        </vaadin-vertical-layout>
        <vaadin-horizontal-layout class="buttonsDialog" theme="spacing">
          [stuff...]
        </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
      </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    </div>
  </flow-component-renderer>
</vaadin-dialog-overlay>
```

The innermost `<vaadin-vertical-layout>` is the element taller than the screen.

Comment: Hey, thanks for noticing this, what version of vaadin are you using? There were some issues in 14.2.0 related to scrolling and touch devices like https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog-flow/issues/188, 14.2.3 has a fix for it. There is still one open issue for a more specific case that only affects safari https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog-flow/issues/204. 
Can you check if your issue is fixed using vaadin 14.2.3. If it's not, could you create a new issue with a code example to reproduce it in https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog-flow/issues/new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was indeed a bug in Vaadin 14.2.0. I updated Vaadin to 14.3.0 and now the dialog scroll works fine.